# How to read a special line in .txt file using Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I have a .txt file, which has next special lines:

```
....
....
!INPUT_PARAMETERS
1 2 5 10
...
...
```

I want to read numbers after comment line !INPUT_PARAMETERS. So, if i have:

```
integer:: A,B,C,D
```

I want to receive that A=1,B=2,C=5,D=10.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: It seems you want to use a NAMELIST.  Otherwise, you'll need to write a parser that reads each line into a string.  The current read string is used to determine what to do with the next line.

Comment: It's easier that @evets suggests: move to the location in the file at where the next line contains the numbers of interest, then `read(unit, *) a, b, c, d` should do the trick.  As to how to move to the right location, well now it is time for you to share with us the code you have so far so we can form an understanding of how much help you need / want.

Comment: Finding the right location is the point of my comment, @HighPerformanceMark.  Assuming `!INPUT PARAMETERS` is within the file and immediately precedes the desired data, one only needs to do `read(unit,'(A)') string` followed by `if (trim(string) == '!INPUT PARAMETERS') then`.  Viola, you've found the right location.  Problem, of course, and why one needs to parse the read strings, is presumably the other lines in the file are important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a snippet of code I use which might be useful,

```
!---------------------------------------------------
! Locate file in input

subroutine locate(fileid, keyword, have_data)
    implicit none
    
    integer,intent(in)          :: fileid               ! File unit number
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: keyword              ! Input keyword 
    logical,intent(out)         :: have_data            ! Flag: input found

    character*(100)             :: linestring           ! First 100 chars
    integer                     :: keyword_length       ! Length of keyword
    integer                     :: io                   ! File status flag

    keyword_length = len(keyword)
    rewind(fileid)
    
    ! Loop until end of file or keyword found
    do
        ! Read first 100 characters of line
        read (fileid,'(a)',iostat=io) linestring

        ! If end of file is reached, exit
        if (io.ne.0) then 
            have_data = .false.
            exit
        end if
        
        ! If the first characters match keyword, exit
        if (linestring(1:keyword_length).eq.keyword) then
            have_data = .true.
            exit
        endif

    end do

end subroutine locate
```

where this is called as follows,

```
call locate(infileid, '!INPUT_PARAMETERS', found)
if (found) then
    !You can do error checking with readin flag
    read(infileid,*, IOSTAT=readin) a, b, c, d
else
    !Set default values
    a = 0;  b = 0
    c = 0;  d = 0
endif
```